# mysqli_fetch_assoc returns zero results in case of 0

Tags: php, mysql

```
$resultLastNumber = $conn->query("SELECT number FROM numbers order by id desc limit 1");
$rowresultLastNumber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultLastNumber);
$lastNumber = $rowresultLaatsteGetal['number'];

if (empty($lastNumber))
{
    echo "No number entered";
}
```

The code above works perfect, except in case of the number "0". In that case it thinks there is no number entered.

Comment: What is `getal`? It should be `$rowresultLaatsteGetal['number'];`

Comment: `empty` checks for 0 values. So you can `$lastNumber !== 0` to your if statement. You may need to tweak it if it's returning a string instead of an integer.

Comment: Sorry, wrong translation. Corrected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> The following values are considered to be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)

So `0` is considered empty.

If you want to know if the query returned anything, you should test the row, not the column.

```
$resultLastNumber = $conn->query("SELECT number FROM numbers order by id desc limit 1");
$rowresultLastNumber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultLastNumber);
if ($rowresultLastNumber) {
    $lastNumber = $rowresultLaatsteGetal['number'];
} else {
    echo "No number entered";
}
```